# The best way to create an "instruction view" for my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Im planning on adding a instructions view to my app. Whats the best way to do it? Load a PDF into a webview or..?
Please suggest anything I might find helpful.
I also want it to look good for the user, not to plain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using a `UIWebView` to load content that resides on your web server. The downside is that the user needs network connectivity to see the instructions and you need to know your way around at least some web development. However, you'll be able to use HTML+CSS+Javascript to create interesting content and you'll be able to change/update/correct that content without going through the hassle of releasing the app again.

Comment: You might also want to consider downloading and saving the html, css and images locally. You can make a mechanism that checks the webserver for updates and downloads new content if available.

Comment: Keep the textual content online and any graphical elements locally. That way you can always update the content later. Consider implementing caching too so the user can view the instructions even without a network connection.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few apps put screenshots into a scrollview with a paging control.  I really like that design, and there are plenty of tutorials online that explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement instruction view different ways:

1) Just put textview and make scroll. (very simple)

2) Design the HTML instruction, and load it to the webview. (medium in look vise)

3) Create attractive design for instruction pages and implement scroll view with pages. (very attractive)

Please review above point and let me know in case of query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a info button (the lowercase "i" button, can be accessed by inserting "Round Rect Button" and changing type to one of the "Info" buttons or in code you could init a button with type: "UIButtonTypeInfoDark" or "UIButtonTypeInfoLight") on your main or first view controller. Inside that view you could put an UITextView with editing OFF and that would contain all your instructions that the user could scroll through and get to quickly, easily, and intuitively